# How to implement a FIFO buffer?

Tags: c#

My data is coming from a serial port and I'd like to store it in a FIFO buffer before sending it to the client via TCP/IP. How can I do it?

Comment: Good. For this you need Queue<T>.

Comment: Isn't this what streams are for?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a FIFO? You can get a `Stream` from both a `SerialPort` and a `TcpClient`. Just copy one to the other:

```
IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("128.128.128.128"), 8888);
using(TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
using(SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM1"))
{
    client.Connect(endpoint);
    sp.Open();
    Stream clientStream = client.GetStream();
    Stream serialStream = sp.BaseStream;
    sp.BaseStream.CopyTo(clientStream);
}
```